# link on li and align vertical: middle

Tags: html, css

I am working on this step by step pattern and I am having some issues aligning the text to be in the middle as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/54vtc0n0/
I tried the align-vertical:middle but that did not work for me, maybe I did it wrong? Do any of you have any ideas on how to align this?

Also, I want to link the blue steps to a url so when you click on the validated step it takes you to a page. However it looks like I can't have an href on an li pointing to an outside page. I really need this to link to a url. Does anyone knows a work around.

Thanks in advance

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="crumbs">
    <ul>
        <li class="blue"><a href="#http://google.com">Start <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-lg" style = "align: right"  ></i></a></li>
        <li ><a href="#2">About you </a></li>
        <li class= "grey"><a href="#3">Plans</a></li>
        <li class= "grey"><a href="#4">Details</a></li>
        <li class="grey"><a href="#5">Enroll</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>

CSS:
#crumbs ul {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline-table;
    }
        #crumbs ul li {
            display: inline;
        }

        #crumbs ul li a {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            background: #3498db;
            text-align: rigth;
            padding: 25px 15px 0 40px;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 0px 5px 0; 
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            padding-right: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;

        }
            #crumbs ul li a:after {
                content: "";  
                border-top: 25px solid transparent;
                border-bottom:  25px solid transparent;
                border-left: 25px solid #009bda;
                position: absolute; right: -25px; top: 0;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            #crumbs ul li a:before {
                content: "";  
                border-top: 25px solid transparent;
                border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
                border-left: 25px solid #fff;
                position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
            }

                #crumbs ul li:first-child a {
                    border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px;
                }
                #crumbs ul li:first-child a:before {
                    display: none; 
                }

                #crumbs ul li:last-child a {
                    padding-right: 8px;
                    padding-bottom: 5px;
                    border-top-right-radius: 0px; border-bottom: 0px;
                }
                #crumbs ul li:last-child a:after {
                    display: none; 
                }

            #crumbs ul li a:hover {
                background: #ed5338;
            }
            #crumbs ul li a:hover:after {
                    border-left-color: #ed5338;
                }

                <!-----------------------The non active state-------------------------->

#crumbs ul li.notactive {
            display: inline;
        }

        #crumbs ul li.notactive a {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            background: #d1d1ce;
            text-align: rigth;
            padding: 25px 15px 0 60px;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 0px 5px 0; 
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            padding-right: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;

        }
            #crumbs ul li.notactive a:after {
                content: "";  
                border-top: 25px solid transparent;
                border-bottom:  25px solid transparent;
                border-left: 25px solid #d1d1ce;
                position: absolute; right: -25px; top: 0;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            #crumbs ul li.notactive a:before {
                content: "";  
                border-top: 25px solid transparent;
                border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
                border-left: 25px solid transparent;
                position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
            }

                #crumbs ul li.notactive:first-child a {
                    border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px;
                }
                #crumbs ul li.notactive:first-child a:before {
                    display: none; 
                }

                #crumbs ul li.notactive:last-child a {
                    padding-right: 10px;
                    padding-bottom: 5px;
                    border-top-right-radius: 0px; border-bottom: 0px;
                }
                #crumbs ul li.notactive:last-child a:after {
                    display: none; 
                }

            #crumbs ul li a:hover {
                background: #ed5338;
            }
            #crumbs ul li a:hover:after {
                    border-left-color: #ed5338;
                }
                        <!-------------------Blue box------------------------->

        #crumbs ul li.blue {
            display: inline;
        }

        #crumbs ul li.blue a {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            background: #009bda;
            text-align: rigth;
            padding: 25px 15px 0 60px;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 0px 5px 0; 
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            padding-right: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;

        }
                                <!-------------------Grey box------------------------->

        #crumbs ul li.grey {
            display: inline;
        }

        #crumbs ul li.grey a {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            background: #d1d1ce;
            text-align: rigth;
            padding: 25px 15px 0 60px;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 0px 5px 0; 
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            padding-right: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;

        }
        #crumbs ul li.grey a:after {
                content: "";  
                border-top: 25px solid transparent;
                border-bottom:  25px solid transparent;
                border-left: 25px solid #d1d1ce;
                position: absolute; right: -25px; top: 0;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            #crumbs ul li.grey a:before {
                content: "";  
                border-top: 25px solid transparent;
                border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
                border-left: 25px solid transparent;
                position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

So using this simple tutorial which I googled: 
https://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/

I was able to recreate your "breadcrumbs" by changing the colours..

https://jsfiddle.net/54vtc0n0/2/

(Credit goes to author of tutorial: Chris Coyier)

You can use java script to change the active link/tab colour by changing the css for that tab, for example:

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Start</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About you</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Plans</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Enroll</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.breadcrumb { 
    list-style: none; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    font: 18px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}
.breadcrumb li { 
    float: left; 
}
.breadcrumb li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: 10px 0 10px 65px;
    background: #009BDA;     
    position: relative; 
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.breadcrumb li a:after { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;           /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid #009BDA;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 2; 
}

.breadcrumb li a:before { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;       
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    margin-left: 1px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 1; 
}

.breadcrumb li:first-child a {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a       { background:        #D1D1CE; }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(2) a:after { border-left-color: #D1D1CE; }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a       { background:        #D1D1CE; }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(3) a:after { border-left-color: #D1D1CE; }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a       { background:        #D1D1CE; }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(4) a:after { border-left-color: #D1D1CE; }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a       { background:        #D1D1CE; }
.breadcrumb li:nth-child(5) a:after { border-left-color: #D1D1CE; }


.breadcrumb li a:hover { background: #A5A5A5; }
.breadcrumb li a:hover:after { border-left-color: #A5A5A5 !important; }
```

Also a little advice when formatting your css, each css rule should not be tabbed in.. it is not HTML. Unless you're using something like media queries or SASS when its needed then go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `padding` is making the text does not centered vertically

[image]

So you can adjust it like this:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#crumbs ul {
    display: inline-table;
}
#crumbs ul li {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#crumbs ul li a {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    background: #009bda;
    text-align: rigth;
    padding: 15px 5px 15px 60px; /*changed*/
    position: relative;
    /* margin: 0px 0px 5px 0; */
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;  /*added*/
}
#crumbs ul li a:after {
    content:"";
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid #009bda;
    position: absolute;
    right: -25px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#crumbs ul li a:before {
    content:'';
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#crumbs ul li:first-child a {
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
#crumbs ul li:first-child a:before {
    display: none;
}
#crumbs ul li:last-child a {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
#crumbs ul li:last-child a:after {
    display: none;
}
#crumbs ul li a:hover {
    background: #ed5338;
}
#crumbs ul li a:hover:after {
    border-left-color: #ed5338;
}
<!-----------------------The non active state--------------------------> #crumbs ul li.notactive {
    display: inline;
}
#crumbs ul li.notactive a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #d1d1ce;
    text-align: rigth;
    padding: 25px 15px 0 60px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0px 5px 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#crumbs ul li.notactive a:after {
    content:"";
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid #d1d1ce;
    position: absolute;
    right: -25px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#crumbs ul li.notactive a:before {
    content:"";
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#crumbs ul li.notactive:first-child a {
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
#crumbs ul li.notactive:first-child a:before {
    display: none;
}
#crumbs ul li.notactive:last-child a {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
#crumbs ul li.notactive:last-child a:after {
    display: none;
}
#crumbs ul li a:hover {
    background: #ed5338;
}
#crumbs ul li a:hover:after {
    border-left-color: #ed5338;
}
<!-------------------Blue box-------------------------> #crumbs ul li.blue {
    display: inline;
}
#crumbs ul li.blue a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #009bda;
    text-align: rigth;
    padding: 25px 15px 0 60px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0px 5px 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
<!-------------------Grey box-------------------------> #crumbs ul li.grey {
    display: inline;
}
#crumbs ul li.grey a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #d1d1ce;
    text-align: rigth;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 60px; /*changed*/
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    height: 50px;
}
#crumbs ul li.grey a:after {
    content:"";
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid #d1d1ce;
    position: absolute;
    right: -25px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#crumbs ul li.grey a:before {
    content:"";
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="crumbs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#1">Start </a>
        </li>
        <li class="grey"><a href="#2">About you</a>
        </li>
        <li class="grey"><a href="#3">Plans</a>
        </li>
        <li class="grey"><a href="#4">Details</a>
        </li>
        <li class="grey"><a href="#5">Enroll</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Or you can use flexbox like this:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#crumbs ul {
    display: inline-table;
}
#crumbs ul li {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#crumbs ul li a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    float: left;
    background: #009bda;
    text-align: rigth;
    padding-left: 60px; /*changed*/
    position: relative;
    /* margin: 0px 0px 5px 0; */
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 5px;
    /* padding-bottom: 5px; */
    height: 50px;
}
#crumbs ul li a:after {
    content:"";
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid #009bda;
    position: absolute;
    right: -25px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#crumbs ul li a:before {
    content:'';
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#crumbs ul li:first-child a {
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
#crumbs ul li:first-child a:before {
    display: none;
}
#crumbs ul li:last-child a {
    padding-right: 10px;
    /*padding-bottom: 5px;*/
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
#crumbs ul li:last-child a:after {
    display: none;
}
#crumbs ul li a:hover {
    background: #ed5338;
}
#crumbs ul li a:hover:after {
    border-left-color: #ed5338;
}
<!-----------------------The non active state--------------------------> #crumbs ul li.notactive {
    display: inline;
}
#crumbs ul li.notactive a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #d1d1ce;
    text-align: rigth;
    padding: 25px 15px 0 60px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0px 5px 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#crumbs ul li.notactive a:after {
    content:"";
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid #d1d1ce;
    position: absolute;
    right: -25px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#crumbs ul li.notactive a:before {
    content:"";
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#crumbs ul li.notactive:first-child a {
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
#crumbs ul li.notactive:first-child a:before {
    display: none;
}
#crumbs ul li.notactive:last-child a {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
#crumbs ul li.notactive:last-child a:after {
    display: none;
}
#crumbs ul li a:hover {
    background: #ed5338;
}
#crumbs ul li a:hover:after {
    border-left-color: #ed5338;
}
<!-------------------Blue box-------------------------> #crumbs ul li.blue {
    display: inline;
}
#crumbs ul li.blue a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background: #009bda;
    text-align: rigth;
    padding: 25px 15px 0 60px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 0px 5px 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
<!-------------------Grey box-------------------------> #crumbs ul li.grey {
    display: inline;
}
#crumbs ul li.grey a {
    /* display: block; */
    float: left;
    background: #d1d1ce;
    text-align: rigth;
    padding-left: 60px;
    position: relative;
    /* margin: 0 0px 5px 0; */
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 5px;
    /* padding-bottom: 5px; */
}
#crumbs ul li.grey a:after {
    content:"";
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid #d1d1ce;
    position: absolute;
    right: -25px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#crumbs ul li.grey a:before {
    content:"";
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="crumbs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#1">Start </a>
        </li>
        <li class="grey"><a href="#2">About you</a>
        </li>
        <li class="grey"><a href="#3">Plans</a>
        </li>
        <li class="grey"><a href="#4">Details</a>
        </li>
        <li class="grey"><a href="#5">Enroll</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In both case I commented the changed code.